# Sequelize create error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

When I try to create a new Appointment sending a simple json within a provider id and a date it raises the following error:

(node:13572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot
read property 'length' of undefined
    at Appointment._initValues (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Studies\Go_Stack\modulo2\goBarber\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:140:49)
    at new Model (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Studies\Go_Stack\modulo2\goBarber\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:118:10)
    at new Appointment (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Studies\Go_Stack\modulo2\goBarber\src\app\models\Appointment.js:3:1)
    at Function.build (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Studies\Go_Stack\modulo2\goBarber\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2167:12)
    at Function.create (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Studies\Go_Stack\modulo2\goBarber\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2220:17)
    at store (C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\Studies\Go_Stack\modulo2\goBarber\src\app\controllers\AppointmentController.js:65:57)
(node:13572) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an
async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13572) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';
import { startOfHour, parseISO, isBefore } from 'date-fns'; 
import User from '../models/user';
import Appointment from '../models/Appointment';


class AppointmentController {
    async index(req, res) {
        const appointments = await Appointment.findAll({
            where: { user_id: req.userId, canceled_at: null }
        })

        return res.json(appointments);
    }

    async store(req, res) {
        const schema = Yup.object().shape({
            provider_id: Yup.number().required(),
            date: Yup.date().required(),
        });

        if (!(await schema.isValid(req.body))) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Validations Fails' });
        }

        const { provider_id, date } = req.body;

        const checkIsProvider = await User.findOne({ 
            where: { 
                id: provider_id, 
                provider: true 
            }
        });

        if (!checkIsProvider) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error:'You can only create appointments with providers' });
        }

        const hourStart = startOfHour(parseISO(date));

        console.log(hourStart);
        console.log(new Date());

        if (isBefore(hourStart, new Date())) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Past dates are not permitted' });
        }

        let checkAvailability;
        try {
            checkAvailability = await Appointment.findOne({
              where: {
                provider_id,
                canceled_at: null,
                date: hourStart,
              },
            });
        } catch (err) {
            checkAvailability = false
        }

        if (checkAvailability) {
            return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Appointment date is not available' });
        }

        const appointment = await Appointment.create({
            user_id: req.userId,
            provider_id,
            date,
        });

        return res.json(appointment);
    }
}

export default new AppointmentController();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a problem in your configurations. Check below:

1. check your connection with your database.
2. make sure that your models are initialized and database tables exist.